# Anchor tag attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the code for my website. I am working on it to make the navbar responsive. But in the small screen size, the navbar button acts weirdly, as soon as I click on it it redirects to the top instead of showing the list items. Instead what I want it to do is to expand and show all the other list items of the navbar. But I am unable to do so. Can someone help me with this?

```js
function responsiveNavbar() {
     let navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar li");

     if (navItems[1].classList == "responsive-navbar") {
          navItems.forEach(function(navItem) {
               navItem.classList.remove(" responsive-navbar");
          });
     } else {
          navItems.forEach(function(navItem) {
               navItem.classList.add("responsive-navbar");
          });
     }

}
```

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
     font-size: 62.5%;
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
     box-sizing: inherit;
     color: #777;
     background-color: #E0E2DB;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.8rem;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 1.5;
     scroll-behavior: inherit;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:after {
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE REUSABLE CONTENT */
/* ------------------------------------- */

/* Grids */

.row {
     width: 80%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

.span-1-of-2 {
     width: 48%;
     float: left;
}

/* HTML contents */

h1, h2.header-heading, h2, h3, h5 {
     margin: 0;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
     font-size: 4.5rem;
     color: #E0E2DB;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     word-spacing: .5rem;
     font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     color: #3D348B;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
}

h3 {
     font-size: 2.6rem;
     color: #000;
}

h4 {
     font-size: 2.2rem;
     color: #E0E2DB;
}

h5 {
     font-size: 2rem;
     margin-bottom: .5rem;
     color: #191716;
}

/* Links */

a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
}

/* Icons */
.icon-small {
     font-size: 2rem;
     color: #3D348B;
     margin-right: 1rem;
}

/* Buttons */

.btn {
     border: 1px solid #E6AF2E;
     border-radius: .3rem;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #E0E2DB;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.btn:hover {
     background-color: #E6AF2E;
     color: #191716;
}

.btn2 {
     background-color: #3D348B;
     color: #E0E2DB;
     border: 1px solid #3D348B;
     border-radius: .3rem;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.btn2:hover {
     background-color: #E0E2DB;
     color: #191716;
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-margin-top-small {
     margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.u-margin-top-medium {
     margin-top: 5rem;
}

.u-margin-top-big {
     margin-top: 7.5rem;
}

.u-margin-bottom-small {
     margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.u-margin-bottom-medium {
     margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.u-text-align-center {
     text-align: center;
}

.u-inline-block {
     display: inline-block;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE HEADER SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

header {
     background-color: #3D348B;
     height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 45%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2.header-heading {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     margin-top: 2rem;
     color: #E6AF2E;
     font-weight: 400;
}

h2.slogan {
     color: #E6AF2E;
     font-size: 2.8rem;
     font-weight: 400;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE NAVBAR */
/* ------------------------------------- */

.navigation {
     position: relative;
     border-bottom: .5px solid #777;
     transition: all .5s;
}

.logo-box {
     float: left;
}

.logo img {
     width: 6rem;
     height: auto;
     margin-left: 2rem;
     border-radius: 50%;
}

nav {
     padding: .5rem;
}

.navbar {
     float: right;
     list-style: none;
     margin-right: 10rem;
     margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li a {
     margin: 0 1rem;
     padding: .2rem .6rem;
     color: black;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #E6AF2E;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar .nav-icon {
     display: none;
     transition: all .3s;
}

/* The sticky navbar */

.sticky {
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #3D348B;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     box-shadow: 0 .2rem .3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.sticky .navbar-lists {
     color: #E0E2DB;
}

.sticky .logo {
     color: #E0E2DB;
}

/* Responsive navbar */

.responsive-navbar {
     display: block;
     text-align: right;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
section {
     padding: 8rem;
}
/* ------------------------------------- */

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE ABOUT SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

.about-section {
     padding: 0;
     margin-top: 12rem;
}

.long-text {
     width: 70%;
     margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
}

.profile-image {
     height: 35rem;
     width: auto;
}

.my-info-img {
     text-align: right;
     padding-right: 15rem;
}

.my-info-list {
     list-style: none;
}

.my-info-list > li {
     margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* MEDIA QUERIES SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
     html {
          font-size: 50%;
     }

     .remove-heading {
          display: none;
     }

     .logo img {
          width: 5rem;
          margin-top: 1rem;
     }

     /* Responsive navbar */
     .navbar li {
          display: none;
     }

     .navbar .nav-icon {
          color: #000;
          display: block;
          font-size: 20px;
     }

     .sticky .navbar .nav-icon {
          display: block;
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 20px;
     }

     .navbar .nav-icon:hover {
          color: #2f2f2f;
     }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

     <!-- Favicon link -->
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
     <!-- Icons link -->
     <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4e3ab997f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     <!-- Rubik font link -->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- CSS links -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/queries.css">

     <title>Arun Bohra - Design Business Solutions</title>
</head>
<body>

     <header id="header">
          <div class="hero-text-box u-text-align-center u-inline-block">
               <h1><span class="remove-heading">Hello</span> I'm Arun</h1>
               <h2 class="header-heading u-margin-top-small">I'm a front-end developer</h2>
               <h2 class="slogan u-margin-top-small">Design business solutions</h2>
               <a href="#about" class="btn u-margin-top-small u-inline-block">Who am I</a>
          </div>
     </header>

     <div class="navigation">
          <nav class="clearfix">
               <div class="logo-box">
                    <a href="#header" class="logo">
                         <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>
               </div>

               <ul class="navbar">
                    <a href="" class="nav-icon" onclick="responsiveNavbar()"><i class="fas fa-bars" id="responsive-nav-btn"></i></a>
                    <li><a href="#header" class="navbar-lists">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="navbar-lists">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#skills" class="navbar-lists">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects" class="navbar-lists">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="navbar-lists">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>

          </nav>
     </div>

     <section class="about-section" id="about">
          <h2 class="u-text-align-center">Who am I</h2>
          <p class="long-text u-text-align-center">I am a web designer and web developer. I design the webiste according to the needs of today's businesses. I do care a lot about the designs with a modern look and feel.</p>

          <div class="row clearfix u-margin-top-big my-info-box">
               <div class="span-1-of-2 my-info-img">
                    <img src="img/profile.png" alt="Profile image" class="profile-image">
               </div>

               <div class="span-1-of-2 my-info-text">
                    <h3 class="u-margin-bottom-medium">I design awesome websites</h3>

                    <ul class="my-info-list u-margin-bottom-medium">
                         <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I can design awesome websites.</li>
                         <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I can code the designed websites.</li>
                         <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I deliver the work very fast.</li>
                         <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I make very precise revisions.</li>
                    </ul>

                    <a href="#" class="btn2 u-text-align-center">Download CV</a>
               </div>

          </div>

     </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is `"responsive-navbar"` class being added? Also you can't have an `<a>` as direct child of a `<ul>`

Comment: I am adding the responsive-navbar class using javaScript. Then what should I do to add that navbar?

Comment: Never mind I thought it is supposed to be some sort of indicator that anchor tag is  in responsive mode

Comment: `navItems[1].classList == "responsive-navbar"` will always return `false`, because [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a property returning a DOMTokenList (an array-like structure), not a string. You're probably mistaking it with [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className). That's why your script above always adds the class, never removes it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onclick(event)` to help locate the clicked item, and find its all siblings.
`classList` is a list, which can't be compared with ==, but with `contains()`.
My snippet can switch the "responsive-navbar" class for the li elements, but the css classes may be missing some properties. I'm not sure.

```js
function responsiveNavbar(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     let navItem = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
     while(navItem && navItem.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li'){
         if (navItem.classList.contains("responsive-navbar")) {
             navItem.classList.remove("responsive-navbar");
         } else {
             navItem.classList.add("responsive-navbar");
         } 
         navItem = navItem.nextElementSibling;
      }
    }
```

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
     font-size: 62.5%;
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
     box-sizing: inherit;
     color: #777;
     background-color: #E0E2DB;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.8rem;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 1.5;
     scroll-behavior: inherit;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:after {
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE REUSABLE CONTENT */
/* ------------------------------------- */

/* Grids */

.row {
     width: 80%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

.span-1-of-2 {
     width: 48%;
     float: left;
}

/* HTML contents */

h1, h2.header-heading, h2, h3, h5 {
     margin: 0;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
     font-size: 4.5rem;
     color: #E0E2DB;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     word-spacing: .5rem;
     font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     color: #3D348B;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
}

h3 {
     font-size: 2.6rem;
     color: #000;
}

h4 {
     font-size: 2.2rem;
     color: #E0E2DB;
}

h5 {
     font-size: 2rem;
     margin-bottom: .5rem;
     color: #191716;
}

/* Links */

a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
}

/* Icons */
.icon-small {
     font-size: 2rem;
     color: #3D348B;
     margin-right: 1rem;
}

/* Buttons */

.btn {
     border: 1px solid #E6AF2E;
     border-radius: .3rem;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #E0E2DB;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.btn:hover {
     background-color: #E6AF2E;
     color: #191716;
}

.btn2 {
     background-color: #3D348B;
     color: #E0E2DB;
     border: 1px solid #3D348B;
     border-radius: .3rem;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.btn2:hover {
     background-color: #E0E2DB;
     color: #191716;
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-margin-top-small {
     margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.u-margin-top-medium {
     margin-top: 5rem;
}

.u-margin-top-big {
     margin-top: 7.5rem;
}

.u-margin-bottom-small {
     margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.u-margin-bottom-medium {
     margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.u-text-align-center {
     text-align: center;
}

.u-inline-block {
     display: inline-block;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE HEADER SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

header {
     background-color: #3D348B;
     height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 45%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2.header-heading {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     margin-top: 2rem;
     color: #E6AF2E;
     font-weight: 400;
}

h2.slogan {
     color: #E6AF2E;
     font-size: 2.8rem;
     font-weight: 400;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE NAVBAR */
/* ------------------------------------- */

.navigation {
     position: relative;
     border-bottom: .5px solid #777;
     transition: all .5s;
}

.logo-box {
     float: left;
}

.logo img {
     width: 6rem;
     height: auto;
     margin-left: 2rem;
     border-radius: 50%;
}

nav {
     padding: .5rem;
}

.navbar {
     float: right;
     list-style: none;
     margin-right: 10rem;
     margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li a {
     margin: 0 1rem;
     padding: .2rem .6rem;
     color: black;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #E6AF2E;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar .nav-icon {
     display: none;
     transition: all .3s;
}

/* The sticky navbar */

.sticky {
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #3D348B;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     box-shadow: 0 .2rem .3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.sticky .navbar-lists {
     color: #E0E2DB;
}

.sticky .logo {
     color: #E0E2DB;
}

/* Responsive navbar */

.responsive-navbar {
     display: block;
     text-align: right;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
section {
     padding: 8rem;
}
/* ------------------------------------- */

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE ABOUT SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

.about-section {
     padding: 0;
     margin-top: 12rem;
}

.long-text {
     width: 70%;
     margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
}

.profile-image {
     height: 35rem;
     width: auto;
}

.my-info-img {
     text-align: right;
     padding-right: 15rem;
}

.my-info-list {
     list-style: none;
}

.my-info-list > li {
     margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* MEDIA QUERIES SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
     html {
          font-size: 50%;
     }

     .remove-heading {
          display: none;
     }

     .logo img {
          width: 5rem;
          margin-top: 1rem;
     }

     /* Responsive navbar */
     .navbar li {
          display: none;
     }

     .navbar .nav-icon {
          color: #000;
          display: block;
          font-size: 20px;
     }

     .sticky .navbar .nav-icon {
          display: block;
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 20px;
     }

     .navbar .nav-icon:hover {
          color: #2f2f2f;
     }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

     <!-- Favicon link -->
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
     <!-- Icons link -->
     <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4e3ab997f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     <!-- Rubik font link -->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- CSS links -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/queries.css">

     <title>Arun Bohra - Design Business Solutions</title>
</head>
<body>

     <header id="header">
          <div class="hero-text-box u-text-align-center u-inline-block">
               <h1><span class="remove-heading">Hello</span> I'm Arun</h1>
               <h2 class="header-heading u-margin-top-small">I'm a front-end developer</h2>
               <h2 class="slogan u-margin-top-small">Design business solutions</h2>
               <a href="#about" class="btn u-margin-top-small u-inline-block">Who am I</a>
          </div>
     </header>

     <div class="navigation">
          <nav class="clearfix">
               <div class="logo-box">
                    <a href="#header" class="logo">
                         <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>
               </div>

               <ul class="navbar">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-icon" onclick="responsiveNavbar(event);"><i class="fas fa-bars" id="responsive-nav-btn"></i></a>
                    <li><a href="#header" class="navbar-lists">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="navbar-lists">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#skills" class="navbar-lists">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects" class="navbar-lists">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="navbar-lists">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>

          </nav>
     </div>

     <section class="about-section" id="about">
          <h2 class="u-text-align-center">Who am I</h2>
          <p class="long-text u-text-align-center">I am a web designer and web developer. I design the webiste according to the needs of today's businesses. I do care a lot about the designs with a modern look and feel.</p>

          <div class="row clearfix u-margin-top-big my-info-box">
               <div class="span-1-of-2 my-info-img">
                    <img src="img/profile.png" alt="Profile image" class="profile-image">
               </div>

               <div class="span-1-of-2 my-info-text">
                    <h3 class="u-margin-bottom-medium">I design awesome websites</h3>

                    <ul class="my-info-list u-margin-bottom-medium">
                         <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I can design awesome websites.</li>
                         <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I can code the designed websites.</li>
                         <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I deliver the work very fast.</li>
                         <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I make very precise revisions.</li>
                    </ul>

                    <a href="#" class="btn2 u-text-align-center">Download CV</a>
               </div>

          </div>

     </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the existing answer. There is no need to use a `while` loop or manually check `contains`

Comment: Also `navItem.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li'` is not needed since `ul` is only supposed to contain `li`

Answer (score -2):

From an inline event handler, you need to pass the event yourself like `onclick="responsiveNavbar(event)"` then you can call  `event.preventDefault();` to stop the movement.

The class `responsive-navbar` gets added and removed correctly with code below.

```js
function responsiveNavbar(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar li");
  navItems.forEach(function(navItem) {
    navItem.classList.toggle("responsive-navbar");
  });

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: #777;
  background-color: #E0E2DB;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  scroll-behavior: inherit;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '.';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* ------------------------------------- */


/* THE REUSABLE CONTENT */


/* ------------------------------------- */


/* Grids */

.row {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.span-1-of-2 {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}


/* HTML contents */

h1,
h2.header-heading,
h2,
h3,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  color: #E0E2DB;
  letter-spacing: .4rem;
  word-spacing: .5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #3D348B;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  color: #000;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: #E0E2DB;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  color: #191716;
}


/* Links */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Icons */

.icon-small {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #3D348B;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}


/* Buttons */

.btn {
  border: 1px solid #E6AF2E;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #E0E2DB;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #E6AF2E;
  color: #191716;
}

.btn2 {
  background-color: #3D348B;
  color: #E0E2DB;
  border: 1px solid #3D348B;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .3rem;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.btn2:hover {
  background-color: #E0E2DB;
  color: #191716;
}


/* Utility classes */

.u-margin-top-small {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.u-margin-top-medium {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.u-margin-top-big {
  margin-top: 7.5rem;
}

.u-margin-bottom-small {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.u-margin-bottom-medium {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.u-text-align-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.u-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* ------------------------------------- */


/* THE HEADER SECTION */


/* ------------------------------------- */

header {
  background-color: #3D348B;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2.header-heading {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  color: #E6AF2E;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2.slogan {
  color: #E6AF2E;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/* ------------------------------------- */


/* THE NAVBAR */


/* ------------------------------------- */

.navigation {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: .5px solid #777;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.logo-box {
  float: left;
}

.logo img {
  width: 6rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

nav {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.navbar {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li a {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: .2rem .6rem;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E6AF2E;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar .nav-icon {
  display: none;
  transition: all .3s;
}


/* The sticky navbar */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #3D348B;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 .2rem .3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.sticky .navbar-lists {
  color: #E0E2DB;
}

.sticky .logo {
  color: #E0E2DB;
}


/* Responsive navbar */

.responsive-navbar {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}


/* ------------------------------------- */

section {
  padding: 8rem;
}


/* ------------------------------------- */


/* ------------------------------------- */


/* THE ABOUT SECTION */


/* ------------------------------------- */

.about-section {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 12rem;
}

.long-text {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 2.5rem auto 0;
}

.profile-image {
  height: 35rem;
  width: auto;
}

.my-info-img {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 15rem;
}

.my-info-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.my-info-list>li {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}


/* ------------------------------------- */


/* MEDIA QUERIES SECTION */


/* ------------------------------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  html {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
  .remove-heading {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo img {
    width: 5rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  /* Responsive navbar */
  .navbar li {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .nav-icon {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .sticky .navbar .nav-icon {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .navbar .nav-icon:hover {
    color: #2f2f2f;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- Favicon link -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!-- Icons link -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4e3ab997f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Rubik font link -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS links -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/queries.css">

  <title>Arun Bohra - Design Business Solutions</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="header">
    <div class="hero-text-box u-text-align-center u-inline-block">
      <h1><span class="remove-heading">Hello</span> I'm Arun</h1>
      <h2 class="header-heading u-margin-top-small">I'm a front-end developer</h2>
      <h2 class="slogan u-margin-top-small">Design business solutions</h2>
      <a href="#about" class="btn u-margin-top-small u-inline-block">Who am I</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="navigation">
    <nav class="clearfix">
      <div class="logo-box">
        <a href="#header" class="logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>

      <ul class="navbar">
        <a href="" class="nav-icon" onclick="responsiveNavbar(event)"><i class="fas fa-bars" id="responsive-nav-btn"></i></a>
        <li><a href="#header" class="navbar-lists">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="navbar-lists">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills" class="navbar-lists">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects" class="navbar-lists">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="navbar-lists">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
  </div>

  <section class="about-section" id="about">
    <h2 class="u-text-align-center">Who am I</h2>
    <p class="long-text u-text-align-center">I am a web designer and web developer. I design the webiste according to the needs of today's businesses. I do care a lot about the designs with a modern look and feel.</p>

    <div class="row clearfix u-margin-top-big my-info-box">
      <div class="span-1-of-2 my-info-img">
        <img src="img/profile.png" alt="Profile image" class="profile-image">
      </div>

      <div class="span-1-of-2 my-info-text">
        <h3 class="u-margin-bottom-medium">I design awesome websites</h3>

        <ul class="my-info-list u-margin-bottom-medium">
          <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I can design awesome websites.</li>
          <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I can code the designed websites.</li>
          <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I deliver the work very fast.</li>
          <li><i class="fas fa-check-circle icon-small"></i>I make very precise revisions.</li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="btn2 u-text-align-center">Download CV</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does event have to be onclick, mouseover or something like that or it is just a variable?

Comment: Still it don't make any difference.

Comment: `responsiveNavbar(event)` here the arguement name needs to be `event`.

Comment: The snippet in question - once the hamburger menu is clicked it goes to a blank white page and it does nothing. This example stays where it is and adds the correct class. Now it is up to you to implement the correct CSS in said class to display the menu

Comment: You're toggling a class without checking the actual condition (if it should be applied or not) and without checking if the class is present or not. This is a common source of subtle and very hard to spot bugs. If only one of the elements gets stripped of all classes by some script external to yours, your code starts applying the class when it should be removing it and it all goes south. Don't do this in your own code and especially don't tell others to do it. It's a really bad practice. A much better solution is `el.classList[ condition ? 'add' : 'remove']('the-class')`

Comment: @tao it is totally ok to use an official DOM API if you know how it works.This is perfectly fine for the scope of this question and answer. ( Bugs occur when you don't know what you're doing, you don't have any test coverage, you don't do any testing at all... lets not go there). I disagree with your point of view. Thanks for sharing your opinion though.

Comment: Your script works fine in isolation. If an extenal script changes the condition you assume to be true on only one of the elements, which happens often in real life scenarios and never in isolation, your code starts doing the opposite of what you wanted it to do, on that element. That's the problem. You're not checking.

Comment: @tao maybe you had bad experience of using an API and you caused bugs. If you hit your finger while using a hammer it doesn't mean hammer is a problem. "Hey, use a drill instead! I had better experience with it!"

Comment: @tao OP is working on his own portfolio website. Not an enterprise application. Have you ever thought of using the tools that suits the scope of the situation? Ever heard of premature optimization?

Comment: The problem is with the logic behind your script. Has nothing to do with testing. (Or, should I say, too much to do with testing in isolation). Your code logic assumes nothing can remove the class from the element after it has applied it, until the next time it runs. How can you make that assumption? How can you make the assumption your script is the only one that runs on that page? Because that's, basically, the assumption you made there.

Comment: And I'm making the tools that NASA and SpaceX uses. That is argument from authority fallacy though.

Comment: @tao you literally miss the point that OP is working on his portfolio website. Understand the situation and learn to use the right tools to get things done. The problems you're talking about occur in a large scale application with numerous people and moving parts. You might as well introduce CI/CD and some AI into your next to-do and hello world application but I'll stick to common sense thanks.

Comment: Edit : OP edited and removed the "I'm making the tools you use" part from his comment.

Comment: You miss the point that you are on [SO], where your answers are read by thousands of people dealing with a similar problem to OP's. Your answer has to be useful for everyone else, not only for OP. The way I see it, you understood the issue long ago, probably agree with it, but have a really hard time admitting you made a mistake. Which doesn't make you very special.

Comment: I never said I'm making the tools you use. I said *"I'm making tools you probably use."*. Which is probably true. But I removed it because it was a response to your malicious comment implying I'm not using proper tooling, which I should have ignored.

Comment: @tao I haven't made a mistake. You think you need an "enterprise/large scale" solution for everything. You're an "I have a hammer so everything is a nail" type of guy", and I'm not. That doesn't make me wrong.

Comment: @tao you said -> "but have a really hard time admitting you made a mistake". Which implies I made a mistake.

Comment: When comparing two solutions, one which fails in some cases and one which doesn't in any case, most people consider the first one a mistake. You seem to have bent this general acceptance/definition of the concept. Which would be your preferred term? I'm willing to go with it.

Comment: There is no "mistake" in the code above. You made an assumption where it can cause problems in a large scale environment which is clearly not the case of this question where OP is working on his portfolio website. SO is a Q&A site. (It made an attempt at being "documentation" years ago but didn't succeed). My answers are tailored to the specific question.

Comment: Most people come here to learn best coding practices, which is what the advice you quoted is all about. No matter how I look at it, I don't see how it violates the COC. A source of subtle bugs is a very serious type of error in coding, as it typically leads to significant costs. I really meant what I said there: *"Don't do it, it's a biggie!"*. Or, if you prefer: *"Don't do it, it's the type of mistake which can get you fired!"*. Or, if you prefer: *"In my estimation, doing it is a lot worse than not doing it."*. Is that better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231118/discussion-between-t-j-and-tao).